# Ubuntu 14.4 needing a complicated boot process on Acer aspire E 11

Tags: boot, 14.04

I have installed Ubuntu 14.4 on a Acer Aspire E 11 running windows 8. When I boot, I have to use the grub menu to enter recovery mode. From there, I must choose resume to have a normal boot or else it will not boot and just hang. Is there a way to fix that?